# Reverse directory search on linux command line

Tags: linux, shell, svn, command-line, find

I have a custom linux prompt which displays various useful nuggets of information.  As I use SVN in my daily job I thought it would be nice to further customize my prompt with information as to the current workspace URL.  This was mostly prompted by a recent case where I had switched to a branch then forgot I had done so.  Confusion abounded so, in a bid to avoid this happening again, I thought this seemed like a good idea.

This has already been achieved by others so I could just follow their examples but I also like to work things out from basic principles.  One thing that I observed about other peoples solutions was that they tended to execute 'svn info' with no regard to context.  Not a problem in and of itself but I thought it might be nice to test for the presence of the ubiquitous '.svn' directory before invoking 'svn info'.

I arrived at this partial solution:

```
if [ -d './.svn' ] ; then svn info | sed -n -e '/^URL/ s/.*svn//p' ; fi;
```

In the presence of a '.svn' directory I invoke 'svn info' then use sed to spit out the portion of the URL in which I am interested.

The problem comes however from the fact that, since svn 1.7, '.svn' is not ubiquitous!

I had thought that I might replace the test for the directory with a call to 'find' to perform a reverse directory search to search up the directory tree ... except there doesn't appear to be such an ability.

Other than dropping the test for '.svn' entirely, can anybody suggest how I might test for the presence of said folder in the current location and all parent folders?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will walk up the tree from your current directory looking for a ".svn" directory:

```
is_svn () { 
    local dir=$PWD 
    while [[ $dir != "/" ]]; do  
        [[ -d "$dir/.svn" ]] && return 0
        dir=$(dirname "$dir")
    done
    return 1
}
```

Then, your prompt can include something like

```
$( is_svn && svn info | ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Don't use a working copy for multiple branches/trunk. There's simply no reason for it. It usually takes less than five minutes to checkout a particular branch of a particular project. And, in this day and age of gigabyte and terabyte sized hard drives, there's just no reason to save the room. (My first hard drive was 40 ***mega***bytes. And, I use to lord over my coworkers who had mere 10 and 20 ***mega***byte hard drives).

What little time and disk space you save will be lost the first time you accidentally used the wrong branch because you forgot that you've switched.

The best way to check to see if you're in a Subversion working copy is to run `svn info` and see what the exit value is. If it's not zero, you're not in a Subversion working directory.

If you really want to have the repo root (or something similar) in your prompt, I suggest a sequence like this in your prompt command:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w (\$(svn info --xml 2> /dev/null | sed -n '/<relative-url>/s/<.*>\(.*\)<.*>/\1/p'))\n$ "
```